# Javascript Unexpected Identifier Error In Console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console

```js
var posts = [{
    title: "cats are mediocre",
    author: "colt",
    comments: ["Aweosme Post", "ur an idot"]
  },
  {
    title: "Cats are actually awesome",
    author: "Cat Luvr"
    comments: ["<3", "Go to hell idiot"]
  }
]
```

I know things are spelled incorrectly I was imitating comments. It says that the error is on either of the comments lines.

Comment: `author: "Cat Luvr"` missing comma after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: code]

if you format the code, you can see that you are missing a comma before "comments" in the second object